# Ionic on ios cannot make http post request

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

Currently, I'm making android and ios application with ionic..
I get difficulties when I want to access external API..
The thing is my code works just fine and smooth when I run on android device, but when I run on ios device, error "**Bad Request 400 Missing request parameter**" appear when I want to access API for login. I pass loginData that contains email, password, and device token into loginService and **bad request error** appear and it only happens on ios, it doesn't happen with android.

Lets's say this is my API_PATH: http://128.XXX.XXX.XX:3002/ and below is my loginService:

```
app.factory('loginService', function($rootScope){
    return {
        login: function(data){
            return $.ajax({
                    url: constant.API_PATH+'user/authenticate',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: data
            });
        }
   }
}
```

and this is code at my loginController:

```
app.controller('loginController', function($rootScope, $scope){
$scope.loginData = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      remember: true,
      token: ''
    }

$scope.doLogin = function(){
    $scope.loginData.token = $rootScope.deviceToken;

    if($scope.loginData.email != "" && $scope.loginData.password != ""){
         loginService.login($scope.loginData)
         .then(function(response){
              console.log(response);
         })
         .catch(function(err){
              console.log(err);
         });
    }
}
});
```

I've tried to add whitelist, cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist

and put this

```
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
```

and this

```
<platform name="ios">
<config-file platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist" parent="NSAppTransportSecurity">
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
    </dict>
</config-file>
```

on my config.xml, I also add this

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

on my index.html, but that doesn't help at all.
Does anyone face the same issue with me?

Comment: It might not be the problem but, consider using `$http` service https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http instead of `$.ajax` that I guess is from jQuery. They are very similar though, `$http` has been built to work properly with angularjs.

Comment: The server which receiving my request did not get any data sent from my request. Server using express, and when I console.log to req.body it returns undefined or null, but actually I sent the request data

Comment: So now it is working but the request data is, somehow, empty on your api method call, isn't it? Are you able to show us the request code and the api method?

Comment: So, this is my api method:

module.exports = function(req, res, next){
var param = {
email : req.bod.email,
password : req.body.password,
remember : req.body.remember ? true : null,
deviceToken : req.body.token ? req.body.token : null
}

// Client input validation
if(!util.checkParameters(param)){
res.status(400).send(error.miss_param);
return;
}
}
}
@LenilsondeCastro

Comment: And this is my code from front end which call the api for login:
app.factory('loginService', function($rootScope){
    return {
        login: function(data){
            return $.ajax({
                    url: constant.API_PATH+'user/authenticate',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: data
            });
        }
   }
}